# Streaming Devices

Tags: video, television

It can be very expensive to make your TV setup open for all kind of devices in our homes.
There are many wireless display standards and having many different devices calls for these options to be available. I am not going to discuss each standard.
Currently I want mostly to have AirPlay and Google Cast always usable when my TV in on.
My current TV setup is;

- 1x Chromecast stick (#1)
- 1X AppleTV (#2)
- 1X Minix Neo X8-h
- 1x Samsung TV 2010 version.

Having these makes me use 3 HDMI ports, and makes 3 standards available. (Google Cast, AirPlay and (Play To, DLNA, UPnP))
I thought that highend android boxes would cover all standards, but AirPlay is bad you have to start up a specific app and the same goes with Miracast. Also Airplay only takes the sound channel when using XBMC on the Minix.
So I still need to have my ATV2 and Chromecast connected, to make my setup work, when I want to share content on the big display.

So I am always waiting for that one device that supports all standards every single time.

Comment: So are you looking for a hub of some sort to keep all these devices connected at the same time?

Comment: Did you find any solution now? I'm also interesting for a solution like this